# Mysql insert select on duplicate key not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

table row with data

| feature_access_id | user_id | company_id | feature_id | access_level | flag | created_dt | last_updated_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '20' | '0' | '0' | '66' | 'ST' | 'Y' | '2022-03-24 07:28:38' | '2022-03-31 08:24:32' |

The below query does affect the rows after running, the flag should have changed from Y to N

```
INSERT INTO access( user_id, company_id, feature_id, access_level, flag) 
select  0,0,feature_id,'ST', 'N' from feature where feature_code = 'UPCOMING'
ON duplicate key update flag = 'N'
```

Constraint that was added

```
ALTER TABLE `access` ADD CONSTRAINT `access_constraint` UNIQUE (
`user_id`,`company_id`,`feature_id`,`access_level`
);
```

Comment: Why should the flag have changed? You do not show any data... As far as we know the table is empty (and we even do not know how it is defined )   Please [edit] the question and make clear what you are doing

Comment: Not reproducible with given info, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70d2a944275c67dd045da27711ae8af2

Comment: 0,0,66,ST combination of index already exist, but that row has a flag value as Y, it needs to be changed to N because the new insert query has N in its value

Comment: Sorry still not enough info, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18c7672eec85e2a824ba3cd2eb8ee407

Comment: what is the error you are getting? are you getting one? 
also, the table you share indicates at least to me that everything is varchar. but then you are inserting Integers, why I am saying it indicates that? cause of the single quotes

Comment: also just as a side note , as far as I know the way you decalared it. for it to cahnge to N your  User_id , company_id , feature_id and access_level must already exist in a single entry. have you changed that this is case ?

Comment: Yeah 4 combination exist already in DB thats why query fails before adding the ON update duplicate Key - Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0-0-0-66-ST' for key 'feature_access.feature_access_constraint'. but after adding on duplicate key - no error shown but the flag value does not changed